# insertmany into the in memory sqllite db - SQLite Date type only accepts Python date objects as input

Tags: python, sqlite, insert, sqlalchemy, runtime-error

I have a table that I am trying to insert many using a dict object.

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
metadata = MetaData()
hockey= Table('hockey', metadata, 
    Column('team', String(16), primary_key=True),
    Column('jersey_colour', String(16)),
    Column('stadium', String(32)),
    Column('goals', Integer),
    Column('date', Date, primary_key=True),
    Column('assists', Integer))

>>>data[0]
{'jersey_colour': u'Blue',
 'team': u'Toronto Maple Leafs',
 'stadium': u'Air Canada Center',
 'date': '2013-03-25',
 'assists': 301,
 'goals': 151}

>>>data[1]
{'jersey_colour': u'Red',
 'team': u'Calgary Flames',
 'stadium': u'PenWest',
 'date': '2013-03-25',
 'assists': 254,
 'goals': 147}

conn = engine.connect()
conn.execute(ins, data)
```

> StatementError: SQLite Date type only accepts Python date objects as
>   input. (original cause: TypeError: SQLite Date type only accepts
>   Python date objects as input.) 'INSERT INTO "hockey" (team,
>   jersey_colour, stadium, goals, date, assists) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
>   ?)' [{'jersey_colour': 'Blue', 'team': 'Toronto Maple Leafs',
>   'stadium': u'Air Canada Center', 'date': '2013-03-25', 'assists': 301,
>   'goals': 151}

1. First question - does the order by which the parameters are fed to '?' matter. As you can see, the fields appear as follows:

   ```
   team
   jersey_colour
   stadium
   goals
   date
   assists
   ```

   HOWEVER, the dictionary order is arbitrary:

   ```
   jersey_colour
   team
   stadium
   date
   assists
   goals
   ```

   Is this a problem for sqlite or mysql? In theory the key is provided so it should be able to figure where to store the data but I'm not sure. For production I will be using a mysql database but for testing I am using the inmemory sqlite db.
2. Second question, the error:

   ```
   StatementError: SQLite Date type only accepts Python date objects as input
   ```

   I found the following (https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/sqlalchemy/EeZbkePPb38), which says:

   > SQLite doesn't have a DATE type specifically.  SQLAlchemy's Date()
   >   type expects Python datetime, i.e. "import datetime; date =
   >   datetime.date(year, month day)".

   The value that is paired with the data key is created by the Python datetime.date command as per what the commentator said above.

   ```
   >>>today_date = datetime.date.today()
   ```

So I'm not sure why the error is occurring. I appreciate your help on both questions #1 and #2. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. SQLAlchemy takes care of the bind parameters and ordering. There is no need to worry about that.
2. You specified in your SQLAlchemy ORM metadata definition that you are handling a date column. SQLAlchemy then handles the translation to the correct form for the backend database. The error comes from SQLAlchemy, *not* SQLLite; SA translates date objects for you.

   This goes *both ways*; even when using SQLLite, you can put date objects in, and when you query, you get date objects *out* again.

The reply to the post you link to talks about the same things there; use a `String()` column if you wanted to store dates as strings, use `datetime.date()` or `datetime.datetime()` instances instead if you declare the column to be of type `Date()`.

Your `date` key is a string; use a `datetime.date()` object instead to avoid the error:

```
{'jersey_colour': u'Blue',
 'team': u'Toronto Maple Leafs',
 'stadium': u'Air Canada Center',
 'date': datetime.date(2013, 3, 25),
 'assists': 301,
 'goals': 151}
```

Comment: Thank you Martijn! I appreciate it. So why am I getting the error? Shouldn't it accept the value in the date key?

Comment: Ooops. I made a comment before you finished your post. Let me try what you suggested by using the datetime.date() instance.