# SQLAlchemy autoload insert record

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

PostgreSQL has table student:

```
                                Table "public.student"
 Column |         Type          |                      Modifiers                   
--------+-----------------------+------------------------------------------------------
 id     | integer               | not null default nextval('student_id_seq'::regclass)
 name   | character varying(10) |
 sex    | character varying(6)  |
 age    | integer               |
Indexes:
    "student_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

I can insert a record like this:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class TableObject(Base):
    __table__ = Table('student', metadata, autoload=True)   

record = TableObject(name="tom", sex="male")
session.add(record)
record = TableObject(name="alice", sex="female", age=10)
session.add(record)
```

I want there is a method to be like this:

```
record = TableObject("alice", "female", 10)
session.add(record)
```

cause error

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)
```

Because I will get records from a file, and split every line to lists, so if this method was supported, it would be very convenient.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert the records right now because `declarative_base` includes a constructor which takes named parameters. The code of that construtor is below (verbatim from [github repository](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/59141d360e70d1a762719206e3cb0220b4c53fef/lib/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/base.py#L409)):

```
def _declarative_constructor(self, **kwargs):
    """A simple constructor that allows initialization from kwargs.

    Sets attributes on the constructed instance using the names and
    values in ``kwargs``.

    Only keys that are present as
    attributes of the instance's class are allowed. These could be,
    for example, any mapped columns or relationships.
    """
    cls_ = type(self)
    for k in kwargs:
        if not hasattr(cls_, k):
            raise TypeError(
                "%r is an invalid keyword argument for %s" %
                (k, cls_.__name__))
        setattr(self, k, kwargs[k])
_declarative_constructor.__name__ = '__init__'
```

So if you would like to replace this constructor with the positional version and therefore it will apply to all your models. The below could be a place to start:

```
def _declarative_positional_constructor(self, *args, **kwargs):
    assert len(kwargs) == 0
    column_names = tuple(c.name for c in self.__mapper__.columns if not(c in self.__mapper__.primary_key))
    assert len(column_names) == len(args)
    for name, value in zip(column_names, args):
        setattr(self, name, value)
_declarative_positional_constructor.__name__ = '__init__'

# ...
# use own default constructor
Base = declarative_base(constructor = _declarative_positional_constructor)
```

In this case, however, the way to create instances using names will not work. So you might enhance this to handle both versions.
Another thing to check is weather the `autoload` guaranties the order of the columns in the table(s) is the same in order to prevent "male" being stored as a name while "John" gets written to Gender column.

Comment: This is really a wonderful solution. And it helps me understand how declarative_base work. Thank you. Maybe this feature should add into sqlalchemy?

Comment: I would not add this to SA for the simple reason that relying on positional function parameters can lead to errors in the future. Imagine that your DB administrator adds another column (like autogenerated UUID, ModifiedAt TIMESTAMP etc for any non-business purposes) to the database and moves it from being the last column to any other position. All your arguments will be shifted. So i prefer named arguments approach as much more robust in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use method like this:

```
class TableObject(Base):
    def __init__(self, name, sex, age):
        super(TableObject, self).__init__()
        self.name = name
        self.sex = sex
        self.age = age
```

?

Comment: I know this one. But that needs create every class for every table. I suppose there could be a nice way to generally insert records through ordered data column.

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628131/python-sqlalchemy-insert-multiple-lines-in-a-tuple-data-structure

Comment: The link really try a method and easy. The answer by @van will be more nice.